# How to automatically filter embedding relations data?

Tags: api-platform.com

I have 2 simple entity related between themselves:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

// use ... ;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     subresourceOperations={
 *         // ...
 *     },
 *     // ... ,
 *     normalizationContext={"groups" = {"category:read"}}
 * )
 * @ ...
 */
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Object", mappedBy="category")
     * @ApiSubresource
     * @Groups({"category:read"})
     */
    private $objects;

    // ...

    public function getObjects(): Collection
    {
        return $this->objects;
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

// use ... ;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     // ...
 * )
 * @ ...
 */
class Object
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"object:read", "object:write"})
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"object:read", "object:write", "category:read"})
     */
    private $name;

    // ...
}
```

I want to get by `/api/сategories/{id}` related data `Objects`, where `isActive = true`. Now I get all the records.

I tried to use `QueryItemExtensionInterface` and`QueryCollectionExtensionInterface`, but I still get all the records. `fetch ="EAGER"` also didn't help me

I clarify, I do not want to get this by subresource `/api/categories/{id}/objects`. I want to get it using `/api/сategories/{id}`

I also want this to depend on the role of the user. So that the admin can get all the records and the user only `isActive = true`

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Boolean Filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#boolean-filter) with `categories?objects.isActive=1`. This filter must be set up on the relation property as [described here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#filtering-on-nested-properties).

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. The `Boolean Filter` will add select to swagger and add an argument to url (/api/categories?object.isActive=true). I don't want it.
I want get related collection by url `/api/categories/{id}` with already filtered by `Object.isActive=true` if current role user = ROLE_USER. I clearly described the problem?

Comment: You should create a custom operation with it's associated dataprovider (see docs).